# Get Tweet URL from Twitter API with GET search/tweet

Tags: twitter, twitterapi-python

I am using Get search/tweets (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/quick-start/recent-search) to get specific Tweets that I am interested, I can get all the information that I need ( i.e: Tweet text,  attachments, and other Tweet objects) (you can find the document for Tweet Object here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet); however I haven't found a way to get the URL to the Tweet itself. I definitely can get other URLS included in the Tweet's text, but not the URL for the Tweet that I am pulling.

Any one knows how to return the URL for the Tweets using Twitter API? I am using the free API version.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find a work around this by combining the Tweet id and Author username.
Here is the function that I wrote. I basically pass username and Tweet id that I get from Tweet objects and create a URL link. (let me know if you are aware of any other way to get the link)

```
def create_tweet_link(username,tweet_id):
  """
  This function takes username and tweet_id of a tweet and returns a link for the tweet.
  Parameters
  ----------
  username : username for the tweet(string)
  tweet_id : unique tweet id associated with each twitt.  (string)
  """
  return f"https://twitter.com/{username}/status/{tweet_id}"
```

Comment: This is a good way to do it. However, it is possible for the username to change in the future. The username actually is not important, as the `tweet_id` will always be redirected to the owning user. So you could use `https://twitter.com/twitter/status/{tweet_id}` and this would open the correct link in the browser (and the `twitter` user is not likely to change username... it is possible, but unlikely).

Comment: worked like a champ, thanks for the comments. I'll update my code to reflect this change and hopefully make my code more sustainable.